# How show banner ads on WordPress Videos, with PHP functions (add_action)

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Example: this is for `wp_head`

```
function add_video_ads(){
        echo '
        <-- my ads code here -->
        ';
}
add_action('wp_head','add_video_ads');
```

I want to add_action on embed, iframe, object and video? how i can do this?

Comment: im so sorry but i don't understend, whats wrong with my question to get that spam!?????

Comment: so my name is the problem?

Comment: ok thanks, but somone have do spam in my question, and i really don't understand whats wrong with my question, so i can edit and fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this using oEmbed.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds

```
function wrap_videos_with_ads( $html, $url, $attr, $post_id ) {

    $ad_above_video = 'PUT YOUR AD CODE HERE';
    $ad_below_video = 'PUT YOUR AD CODE HERE';
    return $ad_above_video.$html.$ad_below_video;


}

add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'wrap_videos_with_ads', 11, 4 );
```